# Contextual rollback with fluentmigrator

Tags: .net, database-migration, fluent-migrator

Fluentmigrator keeps track of what migrations have been applied to a database, which is great however there seems to be no scenario where you can do a rollback to the current version in the database.

So if I have already applied 5 migrations (assuming a sequential id for migrations), I would be on version 5 in the DB, so if I have 5 more migrations (up to 10) and I do a roll-in preview, it seems to know that it needs to apply 6-10 which is great, but the roll out preview doesn't seem to know that it needs to undo 10-6.

The CLI says that a `rollback` task will rollback 1 step by default, and if you were to do `migrate:down` without a specific `version` it would rollback ALL migrations (assuming to version 0), so is there a way to get it to rollback all versions to what is in the DB at that point in time?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, the only way it "seems" to know that it only has to apply 6-10 is because fluent migrator creates a table in your database with records of each migration applied to your database. So in your scenario, there are five rows, with last one being migration five.

When you run the fluent migrator it checks that table, to know which migrations it should apply, so it knows that you stopped at five, then it applies from 6-10.

Now the other way around is not possible off the shelf, since there is no context with the applied migrations, of a certain point in time.

You however override the behavior of the down function for instance to check whether that specific migration should run the down function based on a number that you keep else where, that number would represent your specific point in time.